# Bitwise OR for int64_t not defined?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
int64_t* h_out[ARRAY_SIZE];
int64_t result;
// some manipulations on h_out...
result = h_out[0] | h_out[1];
```

And the last line gives this error:

```
error: expression must have integral or enum type
```

I'm not sure I understand what the error is trying to say, but I guess that it doesn't have `|` operator defined for `int64_t`. While googling for this error, several similar problems come up, many of them dealing with the fact that `%` operator isn't defined for `int64_t` either.

So... how do I bitor two 64-bit long integers? If it needs to be GCC-specific, I don't care about portability so far it is simple. This is a toy task anyway.

Comment: I hope you aren't a C programmer...

Comment: Oh, cool :) I was afraid for a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined for `int64_t`, but not for `int64_t*` (a pointer).

Answer (score 3):

h_out[0] is a pointer to `int64_t` not an `int64_t`

Answer (score 1):

`h_out` is an array of pointers to `int64_t`, so `h_out[0]` and `h_out[1]` have the type `int64_t *`: not an integral type, but a pointer. Perhaps you meant declaring it as

```
int64_t h_out[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

did you include

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

?

Comment: No, this is not the problem. Look at the declararion of the array.